# Making a tkinter scrollbar wider

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm coding in Python 2.7/tkinter in Windows and am putting a scrollbar on a listbar, which I can do easily enough (thanks [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm)). However, I also want to make the scrollbar wider - it will be used on a touchscreen so the easier it is to select it, the better. I figured the width attribute would make it wider, but all it does is create some blank space. What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

top = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(top, width=100)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(top, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(1000):
    listbox.insert(END, str(i))
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

top.mainloop()
```

Yields this:

[image: http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/2619/uxbk.jpg]

Comment: Wouldn't you rather make the listbox wider?

Comment: Also, take the `listbox.pack` out of the for loop. You only need to pack it once.

Comment: @The-IT For your first question, read my question properly. For the second, that was a mistake in my indenting in SO (the real code is fine), since code has to be indented by 4 characters, I got a bit over-enthusiastic... fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

just a few years late to the party, but I have a method that makes the Vertical scrollbar expandable on the X-axis! (Also, due to the current time, this works on Python 2 and 3)

The trick is to create a custom style that *can* expand. This example is pretty useless, you wouldn't want a scrollbar quite this thick, however the concept can be used to create one you do want!

```py
try:
    import Tkinter as tkinter
    import ttk

except:
    import tkinter
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('%sx%s' % (root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.pack_propagate(0)
textarea = tkinter.Text(root)

style = ttk.Style()
style.layout('Vertical.TScrollbar', [
    ('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
        ('Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'nswe'}),
        ('Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': 'nswe'}),
        ('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'unit': 1, 'children': [
            ('Vertical.Scrollbar.grip', {'sticky': ''})
            ]})
        ]})
    ])

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, command=textarea.yview)
textarea.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)


textarea.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=0)
scrollbar.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)` do `fill=BOTH` instead of the `fill=Y`.

Comment: Perhaps then the scroll bar can not be widened. Try Making your own custom scrollbar using the `scale` widget.

Comment: It feels like a bug to be honest. There's an attribute called width, which according to effbot represents "Scrollbar width, in pixels" but the width of the scrollbar - as most people would understand it - is unaffected by it.

Comment: I tested your code in python 3 and I was not able to change the width of the scrollbar.

Comment: LOL You will never believe what happened. I forgot to close the tkinter window for a while I was just using my computer with it in the background, and my hand accidentally slipped and I selected the tkinter window with my mouse and accidentally resized it. Guess what? The scrollbar width changed to what it needed to be! Just make sure you have `scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

OP may have been right it was a bug.
Today I found that width works as expected in current tk version
scrollbar = Scrollbar(top, width=50)

Even works with
fill = tk.Y
[right scrollbar using width of 50, while bottom scrollbar uses default settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glduZ.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31657866)